# show list of files in google drive python

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I want to compare a version of a CSV file I have on my local computer with CSV files on google drive, and if the version of CSV file on google drive is the latest, download it, otherwise, read the local file, I have written a code, but it's not working the first problem is I want a way to access and list all the CSV files in a particular folder on google drive, that's the first step, so this is the code I have:

def rg(mask,mask1):

```
# get latest local file
paths = glob.glob(f'{mask}*csv')
end_dates=[re.search('(\d{6}).csv', p).group(1) for p in paths]
pe=pd.Series(paths, index=end_dates)
end_date=pe.max()
path=pe.index.max()

# get latest gdrive file
#paths = glob.glob(f'{mask1}*.csv')
#paths should ope google drive and list all the csv files
end_dates = [re.search('(\d{6}).csv', p).group(1) for p in paths]
pe=pd.Series(paths, index=end_dates)
end_date_gdrive=pe.max()
path_gdrive=pe.index.max()

if end_date_gdrive > end_date:
    df = gdd.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id='1FBetsMSJD7DIBhWlsgJ72SQltszJtrI3'+ path_gdrive,
                                dest_path=pwd,
                                unzip=False)
    df.to_csv(f'data/{path_gdrive}.csv')
else:
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
return df
```

Comment: I cannot understand `the version of CSV file` in your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: it simply means i want to get all files that end as a csv

Comment: so any file that has extension.csv, example aa.csv, bbb.csv etc

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to retrieve the file list of CSV files like `*.csv`, you can achieve this using "File: list" method of Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) Although I'm not sure `gdd.download_file_from_google_drive` in your script, if you are downloading the shared file from the shared folder and also, you are not using the access token and the API key, in order to retrieve the file list, the access token and the API key are required to be used. When the folder is publicly shared, the API key can be used. How about this?